When using depends_on, will terraform wait for the entire dependency tree or only explicit dependencies?
A simple question about the inner workings of Terraform, for which I could not find documentation.
Assume the following:

I create resource B with Terraform.
I then modify my code to also declare resources A and C.

There is no inherent dependency between these resources


I use depends_on to declare that B depends on A, and C depends on B
I invoke terraform apply

One of two things is going to happen:

Since B already exists, the dependency for C is fulfilled. A and C are created in parallel.
Since B depends on A, and C depends on B, Terraform knows that C depends on A transitively. It creates A first and only after this is done moves on to create C.

But which of the two is it? Both seem reasonable.

Interesting question. I created a small PoC to see what happens.
Creating resource B
resource "null_resource" "b" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource B"
  }
}

Output of terraform apply:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.b will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "b" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "Resource B"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
null_resource.b: Creating...
null_resource.b: Creation complete after 0s [id=1123007074489954098]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Adding resources A and C
resource "null_resource" "b" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource B"
  }

  depends_on = [ null_resource.a ]
}

resource "null_resource" "a" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource A"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "Start-Sleep 60"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "c" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource C"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "Start-Sleep 60"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }

  depends_on = [ null_resource.b ]
}

Output of terraform apply:
null_resource.b: Refreshing state... [id=5916431791595061011]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.a will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "a" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "Resource A"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.c will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "c" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "Resource C"
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
null_resource.a: Creating...
null_resource.a: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.a (local-exec): Executing: ["PowerShell" "-Command" "Start-Sleep 60"]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
null_resource.a: Creation complete after 1m1s [id=6341824471776991203]
null_resource.c: Creating...
null_resource.c: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.c (local-exec): Executing: ["PowerShell" "-Command" "Start-Sleep 60"]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
null_resource.c: Creation complete after 1m0s [id=8942321372455105138]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

As we can see from the logs, resources A and C are not created in parallel.
So the right answer seems to be:

Since B depends on A, and C depends on B, Terraform knows that C
depends on A transitively. It creates A first and only after this is
done moves on to create C.

Note:

As mentioned in depends_on processing and planning consequences, it's recommend to use expression references to imply dependencies when possible instead of depends_on.


Awesome, thanks! I thought of doing a simple PoC, but didn't come up with the simple idea of using sleep to get good visibility on the order or operations.

Confirming the other answer with additional information about why and how Terraform behaves this way:
Terraform's dependency graph is primarily of the objects written in the configuration and the references between them. Each resource block becomes a node in the graph, and then the references (including depends_on) cause dependency edges to be created between the nodes.
During the apply phase, Terraform actually inserts some additional graph nodes and edges, and so the graph contains (at least):

One node for each resource block.
One node for each instance of a resource whose planned action includes creating or updating. ("create", "update", or "replace")
One node for each instance of a resource whose planned action includes deleting. ("delete", or "replace")

The nodes representing the actions taken against each instance then depend on their corresponding resource node. Terraform then draws dependency edges between the nodes based on the resource dependencies, including the nodes that represent specific instance actions, causing the actions to follow the effective dependency order of the configuration nodes.

The following is an illustration of the relevant parts of the graph that would be constructed for the example in the accepted answer:


null_resource.a create depends on null_resource.a config
there is no null_resource.b action node because it was a no-op, but its config node is still present to preserve the reference-based dependencies
null_resource.c create depends on null_resource.c config
null_resource.b config depends on null_resource.a both config and create
null_resource.c config depends on null_resource.b config

All of this means that null_resource.c's create still indirectly depends on null_resource.a's create, even though there isn't any action node for null_resource.b.

I hoped to learn something about the internal workings of TF, and this answer really contributed to this! Thanks a lot! I think I'll have some reading to do about the create/delete blocks - it's not immediately obvious to me why they exist. Perhaps they just represent the specific actions that need to be taken while executing the plan, while the config nodes represent the declared desired end state?

I should note that I simplified things a little for the sake of this explanation, but you have the right idea. The nodes that I labelled "config" essentially represent the translation from Terraform language expressions to the values they evaluate to, and then the action nodes (which are unique to the apply phase) actually cause the calls to the relevant providers that change the remote objects.

This example only included "create" actions, but things get more interesting if you have "replace" actions, because then there are both "create" and "delete" nodes at the same time, to deal with the fact that dependency relationships effectively work backwards for deleting: if A depends on B then B must outlive A, and so A must be deleted before B.

As an alternative to my other answer (creating a small PoC and check the logs) you can use the terraform graph command, which produces descriptions of the relationships between objects in a Terraform configuration, using the DOT language.
Considering the following code:
resource "null_resource" "b" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource B"
  }

  depends_on = [ null_resource.a ]
}

resource "null_resource" "a" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource A"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "c" {
  triggers = {
    description = "Resource C"
  }

  depends_on = [ 
    null_resource.b
  ]
}

Running terraform graph:
digraph G {
  rankdir = "RL";
  node [shape = rect, fontname = "sans-serif"];
  "null_resource.a" [label="null_resource.a"];
  "null_resource.b" [label="null_resource.b"];
  "null_resource.c" [label="null_resource.c"];
  "null_resource.b" -> "null_resource.a";
  "null_resource.c" -> "null_resource.b";
}

Running the following command to generate an image (requires Graphviz):
terraform graph | dot -Tpng > graph.png


Cool, this give us a simple representation of the resources and corresponding dependencies.
Using a slightly different command to generate more details:
terraform graph -type=plan | dot -Tpng >graph-plan.png


